# algoritmo recursivo pilas java

Tags: java

alguien me puede explicar como funciona este ejercicio. No logro entenderlo bien. Cuando entra en el metodo reverseStack vuelve a llamar al metodo reverseStack entonces cuando ejecuta la siguiente linea que es una llamada a otro metodo?

```
  import java.util.Stack;

class Exercise2 {
  public static<T> void reverseStack (Stack<T> p){
  T e;
   if (!p.empty()) {
    e=p.pop();
    reverseStack(p);
    pushBottom (p,e);
  }
}
public static<T> void pushBottom (Stack<T> p, T e){
  T a;
  if (!p.empty()){
     a=p.pop();
     pushBottom(p,e);
     p.push(a);
   }
else {
    p.push(e);
}
}
public static void main(String[] args){
   Stack s = new Stack ();
   int n=10;
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
     s.push(i);
  }

   System.out.println(("Initial stack\n"+ s.toString()));
   reverseStack(s);
   System.out.println(("Final stack\n"+ s.toString()));
 }
}
```

Comment: Se va a llamar el reverseStack 10 veces hasta que quede vacio, luego apenas el ultimo metodo pueda retornar va a llamar el pushBottom, y lo que va a hacer al final es invertir el orden del stack, el cual esta como 10,9,8,7,... para quedar en 1,2,3,....

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es un problema sencillo de recursividad, a tu pregunta, el código entrará en el método `reverseStack` y volverá a el hasta que la pila se haya quedado vacía, a partir de ahi se ejecutaran 10 `pushBottom` de tal forma que este metodo acabe dejando los elementos al reves.

Es un **muy mal ejemplo** para entender la recursividad ya que además la complejidad de este algoritmo se podría mejorar de la siguiente forma:

```
public static<T> void reverseStack (Stack<T> p){
  Stack<T> otraPila = new Stack(); // Creo una nueva pila vacia
  while(!p.empty()) // Mientras quedan elementos
      otraPila.push(p.pop()); // Los meto en la otra pila
  p = otraPila;
}
```

O con un algoritmo recursivo

```
public static<T> void reverseStack(Stack<T> p){
  Stack<T> otraPila = new Stack();
  reverseStackRec(p, otraPila);
  p = otraPila;
}

public static<T> void reverseStackRec(Stack<T> p, Stack<T> p2){
  if(!p.empty()){
      p2.push(p.pop());
      reverseStackRec(p, otraPila);
  }
}
```

Para que también veas de una forma un poco visual en que consiste esto de la recursividad:
[image: Ejemplo gráfico de recursividad al calcular el factorial de un número]

Como puedes ver en la imagen, tu código entrará 10 veces en `reverseStack` (Llamada 1, 2...) y volvera otrás 10 veces llamando a `pushBotton` (Devuelve 1, 2...)

> entonces cuando ejecuta la siguiente linea que es una llamada a otro metodo?

Cuando termina de ejecutar las recursiones y se recuperan los estados de la pila de recursion de Java y la ejecución del código sigue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static<T> void reverseStack (Stack<T> p){
  T e;
   if (!p.empty()) {
    e=p.pop();
    reverseStack(p);
    pushBottom (p,e);
  }
```

> 1) la condicion `if (!p.empty()) {` comprueba si no esta vacio, en
>   caso de exito saca un elemento del Stack
>
> 2) `e=p.pop();` llama
>   nuevamente al metodo hasta que quede vacio el Stack
>
> 3)`reverseStack(p);` revierte el Stack
>
> 4)  `pushBottom (p,e);` inserta
>   los elementos quitados del paso 1 al Stack invertido